# Need to manually sign debian repo

Tags: debian, repository

I am currently using reprepro to manage my private debian repository. I am looking to be able to serve multiple version of the same package in the repo. All of the .deb files for the old versions of the package are still present in the pool/main/ folders, and I've found a means of regenerating the needed Packages and Packages.gz files. Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to regenerate the Release file (thus signing the repository) that contains all the checksums for the repository.

How can I go about re-signing the repository - either manually or with a tool - in a way that does not change the rebuilt Packages.gz files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving my problem with: http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#Setting_up_a_secure_apt_repository

Comment: Cool, glad you solved it. Please be sure to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a **GPG Key for Signing Stuff**, an then **Create a Signed APT Repository**

You can read how: http://blog.jonliv.es/2011/04/26/creating-your-own-signed-apt-repository-and-debian-packages/

Comment: So this case uses reprepro, which I need to stray away from.